# How to deduct quantity of items in database?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm creating a system where I must deduct and add by one if the item is borrowed/returned. In my system I have 2 tables:

```
tblItems(_itemnumber_, _itemname_, _quantity_) 
tblBorrow(_dateborrowed_, _datedue_, _status_)
```

Where if I borrowed an item the status will be *borrowed* and the *quantity* will deducted by 1 and if the status is *returned* the quantity will added by 1. This is my idea(I already how to add and update) but i don`t know how to code this idea. I'd really appreciate your help.

I`m using imports system.data.oledb

Comment: Is it a requirement that you have one table for items in stock and one for items borrowed?

Comment: yes, is it possible even though there`s no relation between them?

Answer (score 0):

First, the underscores might be eliminated to improve readability.

Next, tblBorrow needs *itemnumber*, else all Borrowings look the same.

```
tblBorrow(_itemnumber_,_dateborrowed_, _datedue_, _status_)
```

Then the Borrow_Clicked button would have code to the effect of

```
If tblItems for this _itemnumber_ has _quantity_ <= 0 then
    msg"There is no Quantity to Borrow"
    exit
else
    Update tblItems Set _quantity_ = _quantity_ - 1 Where _itemnumber_ = x
    Insert tblBorrow  Item#, Date, Due, "Borrowed"
End If
```

There would also be a Returned_Click button, with code to the effect of

```
If tblBorrow  for this Item# exists with a "Borrowed" status then
    Update tblItems Set _quantity_ = _quantity_ + 1 Where _itemnumber_ = x
    Update tblBorrow  Set Status = "Returned"
else
    msg"Item status is not Borrowed"
End If
```

Each of these should also edit the Item# to insure that is it valid.

Comment: thnaks sir but could you type it in formal codes :) please thx

Comment: i mean in actual codings. [sorry for my bad english]